# Google Now Event card - How to display more information

Tags: android, gmail, google-schemas, google-now

I'm testing the Event card in Google Now through adding schema data to a confirmation email. At the moment I'm playing around with populating the event card with rail journey info, since the rail journey schema isn't supported.
Unfortunately, I can only get a tiny amount of the info provided to show in the card in Google Now.

Here's what I'm adding to the email:

```
<html>
  <body>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "123456789",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "url": "http://www.eastcoast.co.uk",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Conor Marron"
  },
  "bookingAgent": {
   "@type": "Organization",
   "name": "East Coast",
   "url": "http://www.eastcoast.co.uk",
   "image": "http://losttrack.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/cr-1-may-30-img-East-Coast-Logo.jpg" 
  },
  "modifyReservationUrl": "http://www.eastcoast.co.uk",
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Train to London King's Cross",
    "description": "Leaving at 16:00. Coach B, seat 12",
    "image": "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Observer/Pix/pictures/2012/3/24/1332602521578/new-concourse-kings-cross-008.jpg",
    "startDate": "2014-02-25T16:00:00+00:00",
    "endDate": "2014-02-25T19:00:00+00:00",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "Newcastle Central Station",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "Neville Street",
        "addressLocality": "Newcastle Upon Tyne",
        "addressRegion": "Tyne and Wear",
        "postalCode": "NE1 5DL",
        "addressCountry": "UK"
      }
    }
  },
  "numSeats": "1",
  "venueSeat": "12",
  "venueSection": "Coach B",
  "ticketNumber": "1257250214-1",
  "modifiedTime": "2014-02-25T15:15:00+00:00",
  "additionalTicketText": "Collect tickets at the station. Ref: ABCD1234"
}
</script>

    <p>
      Full Event Schema Example. 
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately all I get from that is this:

[image: Train to London]

So you can see that there are no images, no navigation prompts, no additional notes, no reservation info.

Is there any way I can increase the amount of information shown by default?

The Google example of the event card looks way better. I'd like to get items like an info link, an image, and a navigation prompt.

[image: Expected]

Any thoughts?

Comment: As explained above already, the TrainReservation schema is not supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the image for the booking agent isn't displayed in the card. What about setting an image to the performer or event instead?

From the screenshot you gave, it's seems the dinosaur is the performer, and [from the doc](https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/event-reservation):

reservationFor.performer.image  URL (**recommended for Google Now/Search Answers**) URL of an image of the Person.