# How to show company logo in google now card using google email event reservation schema

Tags: google-schemas

I tried many things and tags including using macro data and JSON-LD, however I was not able to display company logo.

I am not sure about how I can display image, as shown in google sample on their documentation page [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation).

```html
[
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "EventReservation",
      "reservationNumber": "OIU888888",
      "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
      "url": "http://example.com",
      "underName": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "ABC, Inc."
      },
      "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "BusinessEvent",
        "name": "Invite",
        "url": "http://example.com",
        "performer": {
          "@type": "Organization",
          "name": "ABC",
          "image": "http://103.56.173.67/images/footer-logo.png"
        },
        "startDate": "2016-11-18T19:00:00",
        "location": {
          "@type": "Place",
          "name": "AT&T Park",
          "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "AT&T Park",
            "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
            "addressRegion": "CA",
            "postalCode": "94107",
            "addressCountry": "US"
          }
        }
      },
      "potentialAction":{
        "@type": "ViewAction",
        "target" : "<<MobileAccess>>",
        "url": "http://example.com",
        "name" : "<<GMJoinByComputer>>"
      }
    }
]
```

I will share more information if anyone interested, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As I checked the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/event-reservation), just make sure that you review the details of your email to see if any of these properties apply to your event reservation. Make sure that you have used the `reservationFor.image` property for the URL of an image of the Event.

You may check these SO threads: [Can you and how do you embed images in an email when using the Gmail API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461133/can-you-and-how-do-you-embed-images-in-an-email-when-using-the-gmail-api) and [Google Now Event card - How to display more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020184/google-now-event-card-how-to-display-more-information) if it help.

Comment: I already do, one point which I thought can relate to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924706/google-schemas-sender-image) or here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672909/will-the-gmail-offers-publisher-name-override-sender-name/22675087#22675087) . As I am testing this so might be the case I am not able to show the image as from address will always be mine, and email and profile which I am using are company one. Any suggestions?
Moreover, my concern is related to showing the image in google now card, not in email.

Answer (score 0):

@Yash Cauhan I noticed your event type is "BusinessEvent." Through my knowledge and testing, I've noticed that the image only appears when using the event type "MusicEvent."

When skimming through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation) I've noticed the image property is only used in the [Music Event](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation#sports_or_music_event_with_ticket) example. As a work around, I would set your event type to MusicEvent if you'd like the image to appear.

I hope this helps.